# Primary key + Composite primary key causing issue in propel database schema

Tags: php, database, orm, doctrine, propel

I have a table that uses an auto-incremented primary key and it has several fields.

```
<column name="id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true" autoIncrement="true" />
<column name="field1" type="INTEGER" required="true" />
<column name="field2" type="INTEGER" required="true" />
<column name="field3" type="INTEGER" />
<column name="field4" type="INTEGER" />
<column name="field5" type="INTEGER" />
```

I want to make sure that a `field1` + `field2` combo isn't used more than once, so I added them as primary keys in addition to the id, but this is creating problems when I try to use `findPK()`. I would prefer to have an auto-incremented id as primary key but I also want to make sure that the combo `field1` + `field2` isn't entered more than once.

```
<column name="id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true" autoIncrement="true" />
<column name="field1" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" />
<column name="field2" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting an unique index on those fields, something like :

```
<unique>
  <unique-column name="/field1/" />
  <unique-column name="/field2/" />
</unique>
```

as per [propel doc](http://propelorm.org/reference/schema#unique-element)

Comment: Working link: http://propelorm.org/reference/schema#unique-element (edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

And here is the answer for doctrine with yaml

```
Pet:
  columns:
    pet_name:  {type: string(32)}
    owner_id: {type: integer}
  indexes:
    owner_name:
      fields: [pet_name, owner_id]
      type: unique
```