# YAML syntax for unique columns in Propel

Tags: yaml, propel, unique-key

As far as I know to make a column unique the structure below should be used:

```
database:
  table_name:
    column_name: { ..., index: unique }
```

I want to make multiple columns unique at once. How am I going to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're talking about a composite unique key (e.g., having a unique key based on the combination of multiple fields in the same table), here's how you'd do that :

```
<unique name="document-version-index">
  <unique-column name="document_id" />
  <unique-column name="version_id" />
</unique>
```

As for the yaml syntax, I know you can do it in doctrine (see below), but not sure exactly of the propel format.

Doctrine format (--> from stackoverflow thread: [primary key + composite primary key causing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118941/primary-key-composite-primary-key-causing-problem-in-propel-database-schema)  ) :

```
Pet:
  columns:
  pet_name:  {type: string(32)}
  owner_id: {type: integer}
indexes:
  owner_name:
    fields: [pet_name, owner_id]
    type: unique
```

Comment: William -- since there was a way to do it in propel (via XML) that I knew of, I decided it was worth posting (instead of -1'ing your incorrect assertion that "you cannot do that", which you've since updated with what should now be the accepted answer (good find)). If you think it is better (for clarity) that I omit the doctrine afterthought, I'll do so (I'm assuming that what's you meant, since this question is about Propel).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>AFAIK you cannot do that. Oh, and you should use the XML format instead of the YAML one.</strike>

EDIT: actually, there is a possibility to handle that in YAML:

```
Article:
  indexes:
    my_index:       [title(10), user_id]
```

See [this fixtures file](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/blob/master/test/unit/fixtures/new_schema.yml#L66) from the plugin for more information.